# How to reset default application for opening a text file

Tags: 18.04, files, file-association

I know this question has been asked before, but the answers did not work for me.

I have Ubuntu 18.04.  When I try to open a .txt file it attempts to use 'Run'.  I can choose Open With Text Editor and the file opens but next time it is back as it was.  The 'Set As Default' box is greyed and thus is unavailable so I can't change this permanently.  Can anyone suggest what is going onb and how to fix it?

Comment: My mimeapps.list already has the lines [Default Applications]
text/plain=gedit.desktop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set VSCode as Default Text Edtior](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730173/set-vscode-as-default-text-edtior)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an entry for `text/plain` to the top of `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`:

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=gedit.desktop
```

For this to work the file `/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop` needs to exist. If it doesn't, it sounds like your `gedit` package is broken; try forcing a reinstall as [suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/880422/10600).

### Switching the Default GUI Text Editor

If instead you want to set a different text editor such as Geany as the "default", so that "Open With Geany" shows for all text files instead of "Open With Text Editor":

First, create a file named e.g. `geany.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` (there are probably already several `.desktop` files in there) with the following contents. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop) can help with that.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=geany
Name[en_US]=Geany
Exec=/usr/bin/geany
Comment[en_US]=Geany
Name=Geany
Comment=Geany
Icon=geany
```

Then, edit the `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file and an entry for `text/plain` at the top of `[Default Applications]`:

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=geany.desktop
```

Comment: My mimeapps.list is as follows:-

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered before in a sort of duplicate [Set VSCode as Default Text Edtior](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730173/set-vscode-as-default-text-edtior). Just shortly quoting the main trick:

> Set VSCode as the default program for that file by right-clicking on the file, Properties, 'Open With' tab.

See the circle, and afterwards, you will see it where the square is:

[image]

[image]

No new file needed, as far as I can see, as long as you find it in the `Open With` of the properties, else, you need to follow the answers here and there to create a new desktop launcher in `/usr/share/applications` first (but I do not think it is needed). As soon as you have chosen your default program, it will also show up in the right-click context menu.